# Default and Parameterized constructors and object declaration

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, default-constructor, implicit-constructor

I've written this code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Student {
   public:
      string name;
      int age;
      Student() {
         cout<<"Default constructor"<<endl;
      }
      Student(string name, int age) {
         this->name=name;
         this->age=age;
         cout<<"Parameterized constructor"<<endl;
      }
};

int main() {
   system("clear");
   Student s1={"abc", 20};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 return 0;                                                                                                                        }
```

Result:

```
Parameterized constructor
```

**Conclusion:** Defining object s1 like this `Student s1={"abc", 20}` calls parameterized constructor of class

**Testing out conclusion:**

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Student {
   public:
      string name;
      int age;
};

int main() {
   system("clear");
   Student s1={"abc", 20};

   return 0;
}
```

But compiling the code above doesn't give any errors.

**Questions:**

1. Why there is no errors even if we don't define any parameterized constructor inside class ?
2. When we define class data members as *private*, we get some error:

```
5.cpp:12:12: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Student'
   Student s1={"abc", 20};
           ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~
5.cpp:5:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
class Student {
      ^
5.cpp:5:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
5.cpp:5:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit default constructor) not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided
1 error generated.
```

Why we are getting this error now and not when data members were *public* ?
:)

Comment: To answer #1 :[Aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) takes place as your type is an aggregate type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 1st case, `Student` has user-declared constructors, `Student s1={"abc", 20};` performs [list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), as the effect, the appropriate constructor `Student::Student(string, int)` is selected to construct `s1`.

> If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of T participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments that consists of the elements of the braced-init-list, ...

For the 2nd case, `Student` has no user-declared constructors, it's an aggregate and `Student s1={"abc", 20};` performs [aggregate-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), as the effect the data member `name` and `age` are initialized from `"abc"` and `20` directly.

> An aggregate is one of the following types:
>
> - ...
> - ... class type (typically, struct or union), that has
> - ...
>
>   - no user-declared or inherited constructors
> - ...

> Each `direct public base, (since C++17)` array element, or non-static class member, in order of array subscript/appearance in the class definition, is copy-initialized from the corresponding clause of the initializer list.

If you make data members `private`, `Student` is not aggregate again. `Student s1={"abc", 20};` still performs list-initialization and causes the error since no appropriate constructor exists.

> An aggregate is one of the following types:
>
> - ...
> - ... class type (typically, struct or union), that has
>
>   - no private or protected `direct (since C++17)`non-static data members
> - ...